# How can I configure a domain registered at GoDaddy to use Slicehost's name servers?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, nameserver, godaddy, rackspace

I have a site hosted on a Slicehost VPS (diablocomics.com). The domain is registered with GoDaddy. I'd like to use Slicehost's DNS servers...

```
ns1.slicehost.net
ns2.slicehost.net
ns3.slicehost.net
```

I'm pretty sure I have the config on the Slicehost side OK, but I'm less confident of the GoDaddy side.

This was my attempt...

[image]

Although I entered "diablocomics.com" the resulting record is "@". Maybe that's correct.

There's no way to remove those records that say "informational". Does it matter?

And do I need to add records to cover both "diablocomics.com" and "www.diablocomics.com"?

Comment: The context of that screenshout would be great. Not being familiar with GoDaddys setup, not really sure what we're looking at there. It looks like it *could* be correct, but the set up for your domains NS and the NS records in DNS are fairly similar. What concerns me is that there's no section for an IP address in there; every registrar I've ever seen does a DNS > IP mapping to use for the nameservers as well.

Answer (score 4):

OK, I figured it out. I went one screen too far. On GoDaddy on the main page for the domain, click the "select nameservers" link under the **Nameservers** heading.

I went into the "DNS manager" which is only relevant if you're using GoDaddy's DNS servers.

Comment: You can see the full Go Daddy help guide on this here:
http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/664/setting-nameservers-for-your-domain-names

Comment: for someone looking at where it is exactly, there's a short video here explaining where everything is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h3pGjHLmtHs